# Question about flink watermark illustrations in official documents

Tags: apache-flink, watermark

Recently I read flink official documents for something about watermarks.

url：https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/event_time.html

there are two pictures illustrating flink watermark mechanism, which puzzle me mush:

[flink watermark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Vnp.png)

The first picture is easy to understand, But in the second, I wonder how do we get w(11) and w(17)?
As we know, we can define how to generate watermark in the flink job, in other words, watermarks are generated by certain rules. So what are the rules that the watermarks are generated in the second pic.

I look up for almost  all offficial documents of different version flink and they use the same pictures.
It puzzled me much。Is there any explaination？

Comment: You can have a look at this example: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#writing-a-periodic-watermarkgenerator. Basically, Flink periodically generates watermarks from data source and flow them to following operators. Watermark Generator defines the value in watermark. As you can see in the example, BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator and TimeLagWatermarkGenerator will send different watermark for the same streaming pipeline with same source.

Comment: yeah, I know there are different watermak generation rules, which will cause different watermarks for one event sequence. That why I said I'm much confused about the rule how the watermark is generated, instead of asserting the figure is wrong. Even if the figure is right —— it must use confusing genaration rule. I don't know the reason —— the docs and figures are designed to illustrate fink watermark mechanism, help us understand it more easily, not difficult instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're right; that example is confusing. While it does illustrate a possible scenario, it's not easy to understand.

Typically watermarks are generated using a bounded-out-of-orderness watermarking strategy, where the timestamp assigner keeps track of the largest timestamp seen so far (as a side effect of assigning the timestamps in the stream records' metadata). Then each time the periodic watermark generator's timer goes off (every 200 msec by default), the specified bounded delay is subtracted from that maximum timestamp, and the result is used to create a new watermark (provided the resulting timestamp is larger than the previous watermark).

In the example shown in that figure, the maximum timestamp before the W(17) appears to be the 22, so the bounded delay is presumably 5. By the same reasoning, there should therefore be an event for time 16 preceding the W(11), but if there was, it's somewhere before the event from time 7.

Comment: Exactly what I'm confused about! I send email to user@flink.apache.org for help and explaination, but haven't get reply.

Comment: There isn't a time 16 in the figure, Or, if we take the W(11) as base —— the bounded  delay is 4, then there should be a W(18) instead of W(17).But all the computation is based on that it uses bounded-out-of-orderness strategy and take the value of timmstamp - delay as the watermark.The docs don't tell the watermark generation rule, so there still be possibility that the figure is right. But even if so,it's too confusing for an illustration writen to explain mechanism to readers.